# Cakephp3 using finders to load data not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've been following along these few lines of code as demonstrated in the cookbook [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)

```
$query = $articles->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')],
    'contain' => ['Authors', 'Comments'],
    'limit' => 10
]);
```

In my case the code is:

```
$samples_data = $samples->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Samples.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')],
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Tests'],
        'limit' => 10
    ]);

    foreach ($samples_data as $data) {
        debug($data);
    }
```

But i'm getting this error:

[image]

Note: The created column in my database is of type "**datetime**"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks ok, except one thing here --

new DateTime('-10 days') will be returning object http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php , rather than string
a little changes needed here.

```
$query = $articles->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
    'contain' => ['Authors', 'Comments'],
    'limit' => 10
]);

$samples_data = $samples->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Samples.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')],
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Tests'],
        'limit' => 10
    ]);

    foreach ($samples_data as $data) {
        debug($data);
    }
```

This code snippet might work in your case.

Comment: You're great :) This gave me the error:new DateTime('-10 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
So i did something like: $date = new DateTime('-10 days'); $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ['Samples.created >' => $date ]

Answer (score 0):

@abhishek is right. your trying to set an object as string. If you want to bypass the cakephp way you can use the pure php way which would be to change the created value to :

```
Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(-10 days))
```

Comment: Why my Samples.created don;t return object? Its datetime in my database.